how to achieve a filesystem tree structure like tree view in a PDF using iText 7 library
how do acheive this tree like view in the itext library. below is the sample image, anyone have any idea to write tree like view in pdf.

sample code that i have tried, but not working
private fun addDirectory(document: Document, dir: File, indentation: Int = 1) {
    val files = dir.listFiles() ?: return

    for (file in files) {
        if (file.isDirectory) {
            val paragraph = Paragraph()
            for (i in 1..indentation) {
                paragraph.addTabStops(TabStop(20f * i, TabAlignment.LEFT))
            }
            paragraph.add(Tab())
            paragraph.add(file.name)
            paragraph.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA))
            document.add(paragraph)

            addDirectory(document, file, indentation + 1)
        } else {
            val fileParagraph = Paragraph()
            for (i in 1..indentation) {
                fileParagraph.addTabStops(TabStop(20f * i, TabAlignment.LEFT))
            }
            fileParagraph.add(Tab())
            fileParagraph.add(file.name)
            fileParagraph.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.COURIER))
            document.add(fileParagraph)
        }
    }

}

@KJ "Since there are no tabs in a PDF use 2 space characters at a time" - the tab stop handling is done by iText layout.
